# Devilbox (docker) + Laravel Websockets

Tags: laravel, docker, websocket, devilbox

Trying to get the two to work together. Is there something I'm missing or way to debug why it's not working?

Edited .devilbox/nginx.yml as suggested [here](https://devilbox.discourse.group/t/laravel-websockets-with-devilbox/348/2?u=oudo) although trying to contain it to path: wsapp

```
---
###
### Basic vHost skeleton
###
vhost: |
  server {
      listen       __PORT____DEFAULT_VHOST__;
      server_name  __VHOST_NAME__ *.__VHOST_NAME__;

      access_log   "__ACCESS_LOG__" combined;
      error_log    "__ERROR_LOG__" warn;

      # Reverse Proxy definition (Ensure to adjust the port, currently '8000')
      location /wsapp/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://php:6001;
      }

  __REDIRECT__
  __SSL__
  __VHOST_DOCROOT__
  __VHOST_RPROXY__
  __PHP_FPM__
  __ALIASES__
  __DENIES__
  __SERVER_STATUS__
      # Custom directives
  __CUSTOM__
  }
```

Installed laravel-websockets and configured to use '/wsapp'

Visit the dashboard to test:
https://example.local/laravel-websockets

But console has error:

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at
> wss://example.local:6001/wsapp/app/a558686cac00228eb003?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false.
> 2 pusher.min.js:8:6335 The connection to
> wss://example.local:6001/wsapp/app/a558686cac00228eb003?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false
> was interrupted while the page was loading. pusher.min.js:8:6335

Comment: Since it's trying to connect to wss:// (secure) and not ws://, are you sure the SSL handshake is successful?

Comment: https://devilbox.discourse.group/t/laravel-websockets-with-devilbox/348/8

Comment: Just tested without the SSL using only ws:// but get the same issue. 
Also testing with curl get the same 404 response `curl -v example.local:6001/wsapp/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've Created a Setup that works...

first you need 2 domains in devilbox...

1. For you Laravel App (example.local)
2. For you Laravel Websocket (socket.example.local)

on your `socket.example.local` directory...

create `htdocs` and `.devilbox` here you'll add your `nginx.yml` file

when you try to connect to your socket.

- don't use the port anymore...
- and don't isolate the socket to `/wsapp` anymore...
- use `socket.example.local` in .env `PUSHER_HOST` value

run your laravel websocket on `example.local`...

visit `/laravel-websockets` dashboard... remove the `port` value then click `connect`

I don't suggest you'll serve your socket in `/wsapp` because it's hard to configure nginx to serve 2 apps... (it's hard for me, maybe someone more expert on nginx can suggest something regarding this setup)

but that's my solution... if you didn't understand, please do comment